# WebStorm giving "Project SDK is not defined" while editing .ebextensions/app.config

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, webstorm

In WebStorm, I am getting a "Project SDK is not defined" prompt when editing the `app.config` file of my elastic beanstalk environment, and the file is full of red squiggly line errors, as follows:
[image: The error]

When I click the "Setup SDK" link, I am taken to the following screen:
[image: Settings]

What should I do to get WebStorm to recognize my `app.config` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file type of Elastic Beanstalk config files are YAML, but from your screenshots, it looks like your WebStorm thinks that they are something else.  To get WebStorm to treat config files as YAML, do the following:

- Make sure the YAML Plugin is [installed](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html#install)

  1. Hit `Ctrl+Alt+S`
  2. Type `Plugins`
  3. Click on **`Plugins`** on the left side
  4. Type `YAML` on the right side to install it or verify it's there already
- Get WebStorm to treat `*.config` [files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/file-types.html) as YAML

  1. Hit `Ctrl+Alt+S`
  2. Type `File Types`
  3. Click on `File Types` on the left side
  4. Click on `YAML` under `Recognized File Types`
  5. Click the green `+` button under `Registered Patterns` to add `*.config`

WebStorm should then recognize your `app.config` file as a YAML file and no longer prompt you to set up an SDK while viewing it.